# Как привязать элемент Canvas к координатам элементов? HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

У меня есть 2 блока, у которых имеются атрибуты `data-x` и `data-y` с их указанными координатами , так же имеется элемент canvas который соединяет блоки заранее нарисованной линией.

Не могу придумать как можно реализовать функцию, что бы canvas элемент менял свои координаты в зависимости от расположение блоков, допустим если их положение на странице изменится - линия должна все равно их соединять

Каким способом лучше всего это сделать?

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d')


    let width = canvas.width = innerWidth
    let height = canvas.height = innerHeight


    context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height)
    context.beginPath()
    context.moveTo(300, 50)
    context.lineTo(100,50)
    context.stroke()
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#div1{
  background-color: green;
}
#div2 {
  margin-left: 250px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id='div1' data-x="300" data-y="50"></div>
<div id='div2' data-x="100" data-y="50"></div>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: `context.moveTo(div1.dataset.x, div1.dataset.y)
context.lineTo(div2.dataset.x, div2.dataset.y)`

Comment: @hu-fo Будет ли такая запись работать при изменении страницы без обновления?

Comment: что это значит?

Comment: @OnlyWeb, при каждом изменении положения дивов нужно будет перерисовать canvas

Comment: @Grundy , я понимаю, но как это реализовать?

Comment: @OnlyWeb, какую именно часть? Отследить что что-то поменялось? В зависимости от того, как ты меняешь положение дивов - ничего не мешает в этот же момент нарисовать новую линию